# How to calculate resolution total time using DAX in hour?

Tags: date, powerbi, dax

I have a formula in Excel to calculate total time between start and end date.
Here is the formula

```
=IF(M2="","",IF(((M2-L2)*24-12<=12,12,(M2-L2)*24-12))
```

I would like to use it in PowerBI using DAX formula.

I tried this

```
column = HOUR('Logs'[Finish Date]-HOUR('Logs'[Start Date]))*24-12
```

But the value is different with excel calculation.
Anyone can give idea please? I am really new with DAX.

Thank you so much

Comment: `*24-12` what is it for? If you add data sample and result sample then you get exactly what you need.

Comment: @Mik if the different time less than 12 hour, then it will count as 12hours

Answer (score 1):

If you have datetime data type for your column "Start Date" and "End Date", in transformation layer you can simply add a new column as below and this will return your expected output.

[image]

You can still create measures in the report level as below-

```
hour_diff = DATEDIFF(min(time_diff[Start Date]),min(time_diff[Finish Date]),HOUR)
```

Output will be same as below-

[image]

You can check this [blog](https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/power-bi-date-difference/#:%7E:text=Click%20on%20the%20Modelling%20tab,between%20the%20two%20date%20column.&text=Or%20You%20can%20use%20this,both%20give%20the%20same%20result.) for more examples.

Comment: Thank you @mkRabbani, but I need to do some filtering, if the different less than 12, then it will counted as 12 hours the diffrence

Comment: You can add further logic on it as per requirement.

Answer (score 1):

```
column =   
    SWITCH(
        TRUE()
        ,IF ([start]=BLANK()||[end]=BLANK(),TRUE(),FALSE()),BLANK()
        ,DATEDIFF([start],[end],HOUR)<12,12
        ,DATEDIFF([start],[end],HOUR)
    )
```

Second solution:

```
column = 
    IF(
        [start]=BLANK()||[end]=BLANK()
        ,BLANK()
        ,DATEDIFF([start],[end],HOURS)*24-12
    )
```

Comment: Thanks, but the result in PowerBI and excel still different :(

Comment: @Cheries what about the second solution?

Comment: @Cheries if the second will not work then add start/end and result sample. for more then 12 hours and less the 12 hours

Comment: 2nd solution is incorrect too. I use 1st solution by adding -12 in each DATEDIFF`DATEDIFF([Start],[Finish],HOUR)-12<=12,12 ,DATEDIFF([Start Date],[Finish Date],HOUR)-12`

Comment: but this will return 12 even if you have 24 hours difference.. I mean it's not as you say `if the different time less than 12 hour, then it will count as 12hours`. But ok, it's works then its great